# asp.net postback to another web page with dynamic html form

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an asp.net project where I dynamically create simple html form where I have set the method as post and address. My problem is that my default.aspx page (only page in my project) will be the target of the postback from that form submit regardless what I have on the html form.

Is this because on the master page where my default.aspx page is a content of, is a form specified and all my asp.net in the default.aspx is inside that top level form? I know that I could use asp.net controls and give the button PostBackUrl property but I would like to stay in my current design and use dynamically created html code instead. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Yes, nested forms are not allowed in HTML.  In the case of nested forms, the outer form is the one that will be submitted.

Comment: Dammit ;) Will have to work this out some way then. Thanks.